# Having trouble with this FXC error?

Tags: c++, windows, directx, direct3d11

I googled this quite a bit and cannot find a solution for the life of me. I am working with Direct3D 11 (in the tutorials under /Sample/ - the cube one). It uses .fx, and I know it is deprecated, but there are no tutorials out there that don't use it. Pretty much, whenever I build my program, I get the error "fxc.exe exited with code 1". Here is my code in "Shader.fx":

```
    // Constant buffer 
cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register(b0){
    matrix World;
    matrix View;
    matrix Projection;
}

struct VS_OUTPUT{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

// Vertex Shader
VS_OUTPUT VS(float4 Pos : POSITION, float4 Color : COLOR){
    VS_OUTPUT output = (VS_OUTPUT)0;
    output.Pos = mul(Pos, World);
    output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, View);
    output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, Projection);
    output.Color = Color;
    return output;
}

// Pixel Shader
float4 PS(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_Target{
    return input.Color;
}
```

And under the properties of the file I have ShaderType set to "Effect(/fx)". And I don't have anything under Entrypoint name. I am using Visual Studio 2013, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have both Shader Type set to `Effect (/fx)` and Shade Model set to `Shader Model 5 (/5_0)` to build a legacy Effects 11 shader with VS 2013. Make sure you have the .fx file properties set for All Configurations and All Platforms.

[image: fx file property page]

You should take a look at using the CodePlex version of [Effects 11](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271568) and the various [Win32 desktop samples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog.aspx) that have been updated to build for VS 2013 without the legacy DirectX SDK.

And there are tutorials that don't use legacy effects including [Direct3D Tutorial Win32 Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef) and (in progress) tutorials for [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929), and of course the Windows Store apps for Windows 8.x [tutorials](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Direct3D-Tutorial-Sample-08667fb0).

Comment: Thanks! That did it! I also had to put in a few tweaks here in there, but it worked!

(tweaks being bugs in blocks of code irrelevant to this question)